# How to get current time when I hit a webserivce using jmeter

Tags: rest, testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I run the create customer ws  and wanted to capture the date time at which it is get executed in jmeter and pass that datetime into the Create Customer-verify OpDateTime JDBC sampler.

Please help!!!!!!
Below is the problem for which I need solution.

Jmeter Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "**[Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)**" as child of "Create Customer WS"

[image]

Then passe the variable value to your other sampler:

> ${date}